# link_to syntax, multiple options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting my links the way I want them.  Currently, I have the following code:

```
<%= link_to  :action => 'toggle' ,  :id => item.id, :remote => true  do %>
    <i class="icon icon-test"></i><b>Toggle</b>
<%end%>
```

This will produce the links that I want, but include `&remote=true` in the link path instead of actually making the link ajaxy.  Attempts to wrap parameters in parentheses or curly braces  like

```
<%= link_to {:action => 'toggle', :remote => true }, :id => item.id do %> ...
```

gives me errors like

> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'

I'm thinking I want to make a call to the third signature listed [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using hash arguments for the URL, you should really be using URL helpers:

```
<%= link_to toggle_item_path(item), :remote => true do %>
  <i class="icon icon-test"></i><b>Toggle</b>
<% end %>
```

Not only is this shorter, but Rails will also not get confused what keys belong to what hash.

Read more in the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: This gives me `NoMethodError` regarding `toggle_item_path`.  Is this method generated if I do something else first?

Comment: You will need to define a member route for that, which is covered in the routing guide I linked to.